# Returning mysqli results outside of function

Tags: php

Given the following code:

```
function fetchData($mysqli){
    $sql = "select * from `test`";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
    return $result;
}

$result = fetchData($mysqli);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['id'];
}
```

My code is obviously more complicated than this. It loops itself until it yields some results changing some variables at each iteration.

$result is empty. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

FULL CODE:

```
function fetchItem($itemID, $period, $mysqli){

    $periodArray = array('7', '30', '60', '90', '180');

    while (current($periodArray) !== $period) next($periodArray);

    $currentPeriod = current($periodArray);

    $sql = "SELECT * from `test` where `period` = '$period'";

    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
    $row_count = $result->num_rows;             

    if($row_count < 5){

        $currentPeriod = next($periodArray);
        fetchItem($itemID, $currentPeriod, $mysqli);

    } else if($row_count >= 5){

        $currentPeriod = current($periodArray);

        $rows = array();

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }

        // var_dump($rows); <-- returns all results

        return $rows;

    }

}

$output = fetchItem($itemID, $period, $mysqli);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($output); <-- NULL
echo '</pre>';
```

As you can see if I don't get results for a given period it moves onto the next one.

Comment: what are you supplying for $mysqli when you call the fetchData function in your $result var? sometimes wrong credentials can cause empty data-sets.

Comment: Does $result === FALSE or is it the mysqli_result object?  If it's false, then your query is bad or your connection is failing, etc.  Have you tried: $mysqli->connect_errno, etc.?

Comment: @unixmiah credentials are fine. I've tested the query by itself before putting it in the function. I can actually print the results within the function but not outside.

Comment: @KevinNelson It returns:

mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 30
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 10
    [type] => 0
)

Comment: So, if you're inside the function, `$result` has that data, but on the outside of the function that data is gone?  Are you stepping through your code?  At what point does $result lose its value?  I don't see any technical errors with your example, so that would lead me to believe that the problem is in the "more complicated code" that you took out...`$result` accidentally getting overridden, etc...or can you reproduce the error with just this simplified code?

Comment: you should include mysqli_fetch_array in fetchData function and use a loop function to read it through.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:

```
function fetchData($mysqli){
   $sql = "select * from `test`";
   $init = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
   $result = $init->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

   return $result;
}

$result = fetchData($mysqli);

foreach($result as $row){
    echo $row['id'];
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use fetch_array in the method, then I believe that you need to change the while to a foreach and get rid of the mysqli_fetch_array().

Comment: @KevinNelson thanks; I forgot to change that part. Now updated with the correct code.

Comment: Not working. I think I might be overwriting something. Posted full code.